Can't create an event for google analytics 4 for c# application?
I am trying to send an event to GA4 where it simply shows how many users have run the application with the code shown that I got from another question. The code requires an event to send to, but I am struggling to create an event to send the analytic data to. The website keeps displaying "Internal Error" when I try to create a new event.
Additionally, if the create event issue is unresolvable. Is it possible to modify the code below to send the analytical data without a custom event?
Also, I have pretty much no experience with GA4 so I apologize in advance if what I am asking is stupid.
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

    var program = new Program();

    await program.SendAnalyticsDataAsync("application_ran");
}

private async Task SendAnalyticsDataAsync(string eventName)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var measurementId = ""; // Replace with your Measurement ID
    var apiSecret = ""; // Replace with your API Secret

    var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        client_id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        events = new List<object>
        {
            new
            {
                name = eventName
            }
        }
    });

    var content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    // Construct the full URL with measurement_id and api_secret as query parameters
    var url = $"https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id={measurementId}&api_secret={apiSecret}";

    // Log additional information about the request
    Console.WriteLine($"Sending analytics data at {DateTime.UtcNow}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Event name: {eventName}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Payload: {jsonPayload}");

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

    // Log the status code regardless of success or failure
    Console.WriteLine($"Status code: {response.StatusCode}");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Handle success
        Console.WriteLine("Analytics data sent successfully.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle error
        // Optionally, log the response body for more details
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send analytics data. Response body: {responseBody}");
    }
}

The console prints:
Payload: {"client_id":"2df919b8-0608-4e84-a377-eb5e79ae0449","events":[{"name":"application_ran"}]}
Status code: NoContent
Analytics data sent successfully.
I went to Admin -> Events -> Create event -> Create:
I put application_ran into the Custom event name section and when I click create it says "Internal error".
GA4 create events internal error
Do I have to enter something into the matching conditions, parameter configuration sections, or further do something else to get this to work? Because from what I heard what I did above is all you have to do to get this to work.
Also, I'm not sure if this is causing the error message but my data stream is set to web and i set the link to a random one.
